# Sublime text 3, everything is so small

Tags: 14.04

I just installed Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 14.04 and everything is so small, how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the dash type.

```
Displays
```

and then hit enter.

In this window you should see scale for menu and title bars.  This might have an effect on the program.

If this doesn't work you can also adjust the text size of Sublime Text it self.  You can find it outlined here - http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/font.html

which says

> Changing the font can be done via adding these lines to
>   Preferences/Settings - User:
>
> "font_face": "Courier New",     "font_size": 10
>
> and then change as desired. The font will change when you save.
>
> You can see other settings to change by browsing through
>   Preferences/Settings - Default. There are many things that can be
>   customized in Sublime Text.

Finally if none of this works you could always use a lower resolution.  I personally find I run into problems with a lot of programs that where designed with 1080p in mind.  Obviously not something some one wants to hear when they purchase a nice 2k, 4k+ monitor.  On the plus side if you are on a laptop lowering the resolution to 1080p gives you better battery life and still looks good at least for me on my 2015 Razer Blade.